How to use value of derivedColumn in data flow activity as request body of web activity in same pipeline?
How to use value of derivedColumn in data flow activty as request body of web activity in same pipeline?

How to use value of derivedColumn in data flow activity as request body of web activity in same pipeline?


In sink transformation of dataflow activity, select Cache as sink type.

Select Write to activity output check box.


In the pipeline, Add the dataflow activity and add the dataflow that is created in it.

Give None as logging level.


To access the output of dataflow activity, you can give the expression as @activity('Data flow1').output.sink1.value in the request body of web activity.


